# socket.io: server is not created/cannot connect to server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following (simple) websocket code using socket.io in a node.js-project:

```
// index.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected");
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
  });
});

server.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server running...'));
```

I'm using a chrome extension to test if I can connect to this server. I'm using [Simple Websocket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo).

When I enter the following URL's, I cannot connect to the server:

- ws://localhost:4000
- ws://127.0.0.1:4000
- ws://testserver.loca.lt (localtunnel)

I get an "undefined" error, so it seems there is no error data.

I'm using chrome on macOS. Previously (a few months ago) I was able to create socket.io-servers and connect to them on this machine.

**EDIT:**

This is the error in the developer console:

> websocket.js:88 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

There is **no error code or error** behind 'failed'.

[image]